# How to cast string boolean from MySQL to real boolean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs

I built a php backend for my ReactJS frontend.

My mysql `users` table has a `checkedIn` column that is stored as `tinyint`. I am fetching it like:

```php
<?php
// ...
$getUser = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uid`=:uid AND `unique_id`=:unique_id";
$getUser_stmt = $conn->prepare($getUser);
$getUser_stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$getUser_stmt->bindValue(':unique_id', $unique_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$getUser_stmt->execute();
//...
```

And in my frontend:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${config.server}/api/user.php?uid=${match.params.uid}`)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data.message);
        setUser(result.data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, [match.params.uid]);
```

My log gives me:

```
{
  "id": "5",
  "uid": "A0005",
  "unique_id": "1384773b4df62",
  "mail": "mail@test.com",
  "date_checkin": "2021-05-03 11:00:35",
  "checkedIn": "1"
}
```

How can I modify my backend or my frontend, to have a real boolean value for `checkedIn` in the frontend?

I expect:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "uid": "A0005",
  "unique_id": "1384773b4df62",
  "mail": "mail@test.com",
  "date_checkin": Date Mon May 03 2021 17:15:27 GMT+0200,
  "checkedIn": true
}
```

As a side effect: How can I cast the id to Number and the timestamp to Date?

Comment: In php before returning the ```$row```, just use ```$row['checkedIn'] = boolval($row['checkedIn']); return $row```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function `convert` do these conversion:

```js
let user = `{
  "id": "5",
  "uid": "A0005",
  "unique_id": "1384773b4df62",
  "mail": "mail@test.com",
  "date_checkin": "2021-05-03 11:00:35",
  "checkedIn": "1"}`;

function convert(data){
    data["id"] = data["id"]*1;//Int
    data["checkedIn"] = !(data["checkedIn"]==='0');//Bool
    data["date_checkin"] = Date(data["date_checkin"]);//Date
    return data;
}
convert(JSON.parse(user));
```

Note: user has *JSON* format. So convert it to real object using function `JSON.parse()`